# The argument type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?

Tags: flutter, dart

I keep having this error and I'm unable to understand why. Line 5.

```js
  Future _handleOpenNotificationDialog(context, RemoteMessage message) async {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String _timestamp = DateFormat('yyyyMMddHHmmss').format(now);
    NotificationModel notificationModel = NotificationModel(
      date: message.sentTime,
      description: message.data['description'],
      postId: message.data['post_id'],
      thumbnailUrl: message.data['image_url'],
      timestamp: _timestamp,
      title: message.notification!.title,
      subTitle: message.notification!.body,
    );
    openNotificationDialog(context, notificationModel);
  }
```

Comment: What is `message.sentTime`?  What type does `NotificationModel`'s `date` parameter expect?  The error message says what's wrong: you're trying to pass a `DateTime?` where a `String?` is expected.  Convert it to a `String` first: `message.sentTime?.toString()`